# I am trying to modify the code to train my transformer image caption model with multiple gpus for paralelism.I don't know what 'list' refer to

Tags: pytorch

The error comes when I am tring to modify the code to train my image caption model with multiple gpus.I don't know what 'list' refer to. Maybe it is problem of inputs, but I don't know why is wrong.

```
Meshed-Memory Transformer Training
Let's use 3 GPUs!
Training starts
Epoch 0 - train:   0%|                                                                                       | 0/9440 [00:08<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 257, in <module>
    train_loss = train_xe(model, dataloader_train, optim, text_field)
  File "train.py", line 82, in train_xe
    out = model(detections, captions)
  File "/data/zzw/anaconda3/envs/m2release/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 493, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/data/zzw/anaconda3/envs/m2release/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py", line 151, in forward
    replicas = self.replicate(self.module, self.device_ids[:len(inputs)])
  File "/data/zzw/anaconda3/envs/m2release/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py", line 156, in replicate
    return replicate(module, device_ids)
  File "/data/zzw/anaconda3/envs/m2release/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/replicate.py", line 174, in replicate
    replica._buffers[key] = buffer_copies[j][buffer_idx]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its been a while but for anyone still struggling with this I also had the same issue using `torch==1.1.0`. I solved it by upgrading my torch to `1.7.1`